# pyspark to broadcast or not to broadcast

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, broadcast

I have implemented the same function `dotproduct` once with  `broadcast` and once without

```py
shared = [1, 2 , 3, 4, 5]
broadcasted = sc.broadcast(shared)

def dotproduct_shared(vector):
   return sum([v*w for v,w in zip(vector,shared)])

def dotproduct_broadcast(vector):
   return sum([v*w for v,w in zip(vector, broadcasted.value)])
```

They both work,

the question is: what is the difference ?

Why should I use broadcast ?

Comment: I believe @AlbertoBonsanto is right. It's a duplicate.

Comment: It could be dupe guys but the answer is wrong I believe.

Comment: @zero323, don't leave me hanging, what is the right answer?

Comment: @UriGoren A fundamental difference is a liftime. Broadcast variables are persistent and can be reused, variables passed in closures are ephemeral and have to be resend for each stage it is using it.

Comment: This question is not duplicate. Way broadcast variable is shared in Spark (Scala) and PySpark (Python) is different because of underlying executors being thread based vs process based.